# How to get Library Name using sp.web.getFileByUrl

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnpjs

Is there any way to get the library name in the SP.web.getFileByUrl.

I have tried the below code but not getting library name

```
let result = await sp.web.getFileByUrl("https://sample.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/SampleSite/SampleLibrary/test/test.docx?d=w1db9f77e26354f7e8301ff3ddda7dff0&csf=1&web=1&e=O2hf6u").select("*").get()
```

Comment: This endpoint is specific to get the file/document using the URL. What is the exact requirement behind getting document library name? Do you need this in SPFx web part or extension?

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
The below Shantha kumar's code worked for me. Based on the Library Name , I need to get the drive id of that library for thumbnail preview of the documents using graph api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the List id from the getFileByUrl method. Based on that, we can get the List Name and its information.

```
  const file = await sp.web.getFileByUrl("https://sample.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/SampleSite/SampleLibrary/test/test.docx?d=w1db9f77e26354f7e8301ff3ddda7dff0&csf=1&web=1&e=O2hf6u").select('ListId').get()
  const list = await sp.web.lists.getById(file.ListId).get()
  console.log('List Name: '+ list.Title)
```

Hope this helps in getting the List details

Comment: Thanks @Shantha Kumar Thambidurai, I have used * in select but i didn't given listId explicitly to get that.